# jquery insert a text between two tags (ie: <b><span>inserted text</span></b> )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a short script for an HTML table and when you click on a cell you can modify its content and with a save button you can save it. Of course just for temporarily as I only modify the DOM.

I wanted the save button (text) in red color, so I'd like to put inside a  tag.

I'm very close to the solution, but I just really stuck at this last step.

Here is my code:

```
  <style>
b {
  color: red;
  }
```

```
<table border='1' id="editTable">
  <tr>
    <td><span>John</span></td>
    <td><span>Doe</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Jane</span></td>
    <td><span>Doe</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
const table = document.getElementById('editTable');

table.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
    const button = e.target;
    const td = button.parentNode;
    const span = td.firstElementChild;
    if (button.textContent === span.textContent) {
      const b = document.createElement('b');
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.value = span.textContent;
      td.insertBefore(input, span);
      td.insertBefore(b, span);
      button.textContent = '-=>SAVE<=-';
    } else if (button.textContent === '-=>SAVE<=-') {
      const input = td.firstElementChild;
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.textContent = input.value;
      td.insertBefore(span, input);
      td.removeChild(input);
      button.textContent = '';
    }
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zlederer/1vwsyagm)

Comment: I don't know when your question title updated with `Jquery` .. anyway I updated my answer with jquery code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problems are :**

1- Your code didn't append `<span>` to `<b>`

2- no need to confuse yourself with `button` while its `span`

3- no need to use `const span = td.firstElementChild;` while you use `e.target.textContent` which will return the text of the clicked span

4- change `const td = button.parentNode;` to `const td = span.closest('td');` because the `td` will no longer a parent node to the `span` inside `b`

**Pure Javascript**

```js
const table = document.getElementById('editTable');

table.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'SPAN') {
    const span = e.target;
    const td = span.closest('td');
    if (span.textContent !== '-=>SAVE<=-') {
      const b = document.createElement('b');
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.value = span.textContent;
      span.textContent = '-=>SAVE<=-';
      b.appendChild(span);
      td.appendChild(b);
      td.insertBefore(input, b);
    } else {
      const input = td.firstElementChild;
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.textContent = input.value;
      td.innerHTML = '';
      td.appendChild(span);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
b {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table border='1' id="editTable">
  <tr>
    <td><span>John</span></td>
    <td><span>Doe</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Jane</span></td>
    <td><span>Doe</span></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#editTable span' , function(){
  var getText = $(this).text();
  if(getText !== '-=SAVE=-'){
    $(this).closest('td').html('<input type="text" value="'+getText+'"/>'+
               '<b><span>-=SAVE=-</span><b>'
              );
  }else{
    var inputVlaue = $(this).closest('td').find('input').val();
    $(this).closest('td').html('<span>'+inputVlaue+'</span>');
    
  }
});
```

```css
b {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' id="editTable">
  <tr>
    <td><span>John</span></td>
    <td><span>Doe</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Jane</span></td>
    <td><span>Doe</span></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: have you seen I posted `button.style.` just after you post your method 1?

Comment: @DanielH did you see it right now?? good notice .. hope you check other answers before and while writing your answer

Comment: Thank you Mohamed your help and you corrected my code.
I'm just at the beginning of learning javascript and jquery and as you wrote what mistakes I did, it helps a lot.

Comment: You're totally welcome @Zoltan .. Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0):

No need to add a custom tag and extra CSS, just add `button.style.color = 'red';` after you inserted the SAVE

```js
const table = document.getElementById('editTable');

table.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
    const button = e.target;
    const td = button.parentNode;
    const span = td.firstElementChild;
    if (button.textContent === span.textContent) {
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.value = span.textContent;
      td.insertBefore(input, span);
      button.textContent = '-=>SAVE<=-';
      button.style.color = 'red';
    } else if (button.textContent === '-=>SAVE<=-') {
      const input = td.firstElementChild;
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.textContent = input.value;
      td.insertBefore(span, input);
      td.removeChild(input);
      button.textContent = '';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<table border='1' id="editTable">
  <tr>
    <td><span>John</span></td>
    <td><span>Doe</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Jane</span></td>
    <td><span>Doe</span></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class

```
.red {
color: red;
}
```

and after that

```
button.textContent = '-=>SAVE<=-';
button.className += "red";
```

Comment: And what is the difference between your answer and my answer??

Comment: I don't know it just take time to write down my answer :)